# CSS3 transition transform rotateX in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, rotation, translation, transform

I have some problem with rotateX on Chrome browser.

Sometimes I see nice transition, but sometimes mostly on Chrome I see weird animation happen.

Div is not rotated but loosing height from the top until it reaches 0 and then like end frame pops up - to look as it should after transition ends.

This is the problem I've experienced with many examples around the net, but I also prepared mine: http://ugol.pl/test/drop1.html

Can you tell me more about this issue, is this some kind of bug or did I do something wrong inside my CSS?

EDIT:

```
Chrome: Version 31.0.1650.57 m
```

EDIT:

```
<style>
#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
#content {
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.spec {
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-perspective: 800px;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    perspective: 800px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.begin {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 3s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
}
.end {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom;
    transform-origin: bottom;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test b</h1>

<div style="width:800px;height:600px;position:relative;">
    <div id="wrapper" class="spec">
        <div id="content" class="begin">
Lorem ipsum 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="other" style="position:relative;">
Lorem ipsum
</div>
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    var one = document.getElementById("content");
    one.classList.add("end");
}, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Version 31.0.1650.57 m

Comment: I was able to see the issue using the same version of Chrome. It happened 2/8 times I tried. For me on those two occasions it seemed to rotate past the usual degree during the transition (sped up due to the increased degree) then jump back to the usual end frame. @user3008543 Can you post the code or perhaps a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but giving `#wrapper` a `transition` seemed to fix the problem (for the 30 or so trials that I did). The easiest way to apply it would be to give `#wrapper` the class `begin` in addition to `spec`

```
<div id="wrapper" class="spec begin">
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CwRr6/)

Really  weird error though, not sure why a `transition` would necessary